# mass updating table [settings] with different values in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I want a better way to update table such as the following:

```
|name           |value
--------------------------------------
|cache_lifespan |240
|idle_time      |900
|jump_menu      |1
|listing        |25
|system_off     |1
```

The above are settings value, I have them in a form and user with privileges can update them. I am using the following method inside the model 'Setting' to update each setting value but I feel it not the perfect way to do it.

```
public function updateSettings($fields)
{
    Setting::where('name', 'system_off')->update(['value' => $fields['system_off']]);
    Setting::where('name', 'listing')->update(['value' => $fields['listing']]);
    Setting::where('name', 'jump_menu')->update(['value' => $fields['jump_menu']]);
    Setting::where('name', 'cache_lifespan')->update(['value' => $fields['cache_lifespan']]);
    Setting::where('name', 'idle_time')->update(['value' => $fields['idle_time']]);

    cache()->forget('settings');

}
```

I was trying to find a way to update all settings with one query.

Comment: Which version of Laravel you can use now ?

Answer (score 1):

Because you are trying to update same table with different criteria with different valuse it is not possible.
Also you try update many items and you must be use transactions.
I can suggest you use this code

```
$updatedColumns = ['system_off', 'listing', 'jump_menu', 'cache_lifespan', 'idle_time'];
DB::beginTransaction();
foreach ($updatedColumns as $column) {
    if (!Setting::where('name', $column)->update(['value' => $fields[$column]])) {
        DB::rollBack();        
    }
}
DB::commit();
```

if you don't wont  use transactions you can use this code

```
$updatedColumns = ['system_off', 'listing', 'jump_menu', 'cache_lifespan', 'idle_time'];
foreach ($updatedColumns as $column) {
    Setting::where('name', $column)->update(['value' => $fields[$column]]);
}
```

Comment: what if I got more settings list? I have to update the method every time. I want something that take the values automatically from the request array matching it with the one from the DB.

Comment: if your `$fields` keys correspond `name` column value that case you can change only `$updatedColumns = array_keys($fields);` and it is works finly

Comment: @JaydeepMor please provide your solution then. Davit it's worked!